# Silverlight 4 Asynchronous Issue

Tags: authentication, silverlight-4.0, asynchronous

I am creating an application in Silverlight 4. The first screen the user comes in contact with is the Login screen (Login.xaml). I have written the following code in Login.xaml.cs file.

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //first validate if the user is authorised for this application
    if (this.ValidateEntry())
    {
        if (UserAuthenticationBL.AuthenticateUser(txtUserName.Text.Trim(), txtPassword.Password.Trim()))
        {
            //since the user is authenticated we will show the dashboard screen
            this.Content = new MainPage();
        }
        else
        {
            this.ShowErrorMessage("Invalid username or password");
            txtUserName.Focus();
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that the code gets executed before i get the data in the AuthenticateUser method. The code immediately comes down to the "Invalid username or password" and the list is loaded after all the execution on the xaml page has finished.

I know there is something going wrong with the Asynchronous thingi...and i also know i need to put an event to know when the loading has completed........

but i dont know how to go about it!!!
can someone please put some light on this issue...

thank you.

Comment: What is the AuthenticateUser method doing?  It looks like it's returning a bool, but if that's the case is it doing the authentication synchronously?

Comment: It is really important for you to include the code of the AuthenticateUser method, otherwise it is hard to understand the execution flow. This code is (as far as I can tell) executed when you click a "Submit" button, is this assumption correct or is it part of the problem that this code is running before you click that button?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it right, your AuthenticateUser method is running async, right?

You have to define a callback to the AuthenticateUserComplete event and run the method in the button submit event. In the callback  write this if/else clause, then it will be called once the asynchronous method was completed.

Just one question, why are you doing asynchronously if your behavior should be synchronous? (You have to get the answer before deciding what to do).

This http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719598%28VS.71%29.aspx
may be helpful :)

Oscar

Comment: All Silverlight (server) requests are Async.

Comment: Sure sure, sorry! missed the "silverlight" part ;)